# Go to Next Input when I press Enter : ng-zorro

Tags: javascript, angular, keyboard-events

I am using Angular Ng-Zorro library

I have a simple Form.

My client have a custom requirement that he should be able to go to next input when press ENTER

I am not sure, if a custom JavaScript function (or something like that) can be written to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If possible, I'd suggest pushing your client to learn to press tab instead. What you are asking is not only difficult (maybe impossible) to achieve, but also unintuitive for users